# Show variables mysql - where can I find file for those parameters

Tags: mysql, macos

When the following command is executed it shows ton of vairables.

mysql>show variables;

But, what is the location of file which loads. In /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf shows almost a empty file and is listed below.

Where and how can I modify the parameters like port?

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment: Check: [4.2.6 Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html).

Comment: Lots of these variables are pre defined. Many of them can be changes via my.ini file. I don't think the above is all you have in your my.ini file. This may be a different file that what you are using. What OS are you running mysql on?

Answer (score 0):

You can trace the location of your config file through the following command

```
>> mysql --verbose --help | grep -A 1 'Default options'

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```